# Iterations over a private list questions

Tags: java, list, exception, iteration, private

I've got a class `SomeClass` that's got a `List<String> someList` in it. I need to let other classes iterate over the list elements but without letting them change the list or the list elements. Testing the following code:

```
public class SomeClass {
    static private List<String> someList;

    public static List<String> getSomeList() {
        return someList;
    }
    SomeClass(Array<String> someArray){
        someList=Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(someArray));
    }

}
public class DoSomething {
    for (String s : SomeClass.getSomeList()){
    s+="Gotcha";
    }
}
```

Will show that s will change only within that for loop - once it's finished getSomeList() will return the good old list so no changes are saved. Also trying to call getSomeList().add("someString") will result in an exception: UnsupportedOperationException.
Please explain (to a veteran C coder) the logic behind this behavior and how do I catch that exception?

Comment: You are not showing enough of `SomeClass`. I can't see a reason for a `UnsupportedOperationException` when trying to call `add()`.

Comment: @jlordo: I've added the missing line of code (I think)

Comment: This won't even compile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+=` operator of String in fact create a new instance of a String instead of modifying your original string object.  In other words, the following two lines of code are equivalent:

```
s += "Gotcha"
s = new String(s + "Gotcha");
```

---

***Example***

Below is an example doing something similar to your `doSomeThing`

```
public class st {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String hello = "hello";
    String helloReference = hello; // making helloReference and hello refer to same object.
    helloReference += " world"; // perform +=
    System.out.format("`hello` = %s, `helloReference` = %s\n",
        hello, helloReference);
  }
}
```

and its output is the following, which shows that the object referred by `hello` is not affected by the `+=` operator performed by `helloReference`:

```
hello = `hello`, helloReference = `hello world`
```

In other world, before the += operator:

```
    hello            helloReference
      |                     |
   -------------------------------
   |        "hello"              |
   -------------------------------
```

after the += operator, it will create an new instance and modify the object which `helloReference` referenced to:

```
    hello            helloReference
      |                     |             --------------------
      |                     --------------|   "hello world"  |
   -------------------------------        --------------------
   |        "hello"              |
   -------------------------------
```

---

So your code is safe to go, the action performed in you doSomeThing will affect the objects referred by your SomeClass:

```
public class DoSomething {
  for (String s : SomeClass.getSomeList()){
    // this create an new string instance to s
    s+="Gotcha"; 
  }
}
```

Comment: what your saying is that java passes references not pointers. Is there a way to pass a pointer in Java (That's the C programmer in me talking...). And +1 for the text graphics.

Comment: just the `=` can pass the reference in Java, the difference is the immutability of `String`, which will create a new instance when necessary.

Comment: For those classes which are designed immutable, you have no way to change it after its creation.

Answer (score 2):

For List, Use the [Collections.unmodifiableList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) to return a List which is not modifiable outside (i.e., you can still modify the List inside your `SomeClass`).

```
public List<String> getInternalList() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(someList);
}
```

For String, it is safe to return since String is a [immutable class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Answer (score 2):

> once it's finished getSomeList() will return the good old list so no
>   changes are saved.

Because, [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) so the change is not reflected in the final list.. Use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) instead of `String` as the elements of list.

> Also trying to call getSomeList().add("someString") will result in an
>   exception: UnsupportedOperationException.

Because, [`Arrays.asList(someArray)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.asList%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) is returning the [`Arrays.ArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.ArrayList) which is the nested class defined within `Arrays` class as follows:

```
private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
         implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable
```

And this class is extending [`AbstractList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList) which in turn extends [`AbstractCollection`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection). The nested class `ArrayList` is not overriding the [`add(E e)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList.add%28java.lang.Object%29) method of `AbstractList`. So, when you call `add()` on this `List` it makes call to the [`add(E e)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.add%28java.lang.Object%29) method of `AbstractCollection` which is defined as follows within it:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
             throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
```

That's why you are getting [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) while calling `add("something")`.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are **immutable** objects, so you cannot change them like that.

Second of all, you cannot execute code in the class body. `DoSomething` class should have a method that does that:

```
public class DoSomething {

    public static void doSomething() {
         //code            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc ,
List stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly") , it will give you a Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.
So any modification to this list will result in java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException even if dont have the following in the code
Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(someArray));